# The return value of puts function in C

Tags: c, return, printf, puts

I am learning about the functions and the return values, I know that the function `puts` returns a non-negative integer (I am assuming the number of characters printed) or an `EOF` for any error, But when will it return zero? I think the minimum number `puts` can return is 1 (it prints a newline character by default).

In the code attached below. The `puts` would return `1` and the `printf` would return `0`. I want to know when will `puts` return zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%d",puts("")); 
    puts("");
    printf("%d",printf(""));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it will ever return zero? As you've already concluded, that should never happen since it will always print a new line character.

Comment: Puts returns a "non negative integer"

Comment: Why is it given it returns a "non - negative value" if it can't return 0?

Comment: @Shashaank Because the number of printed characters is always a positive value, whereas EOF is always a negative value, but C doesn't otherwise specify the exact value of EOF. Thus the opposite of returning EOF is to return a non-negative value.

Comment: Btw I am just learning C programming, when I read it returns a "non-negative" value, I was confused on how will puts return zero

Comment: @Lundin actually `puts` can very well return 0. The return value is not specified to be the length of the output string.

Comment: @Jabberwocky If it didn't print a new line character then it wasn't a successful write, now was it? In case it fails to print the new line character but doesn't return EOF, the implementation is non-conforming.

Comment: @Lundin  from the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/puts): _On failure, returns EOF_. So if it didn't print a new line character then it wasn't a successful write and then it would return EOF and not 0.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I think the question boils down to "Why does the documentation say `non-negative` instead of `> 0` if it will never return 0 anyway"

Comment: @JohnDoe Yeah, That is my question

Comment: @JohnDoe why doesn't it return 0?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Because those who implemented `puts` decided that it should be a useful function suitable to be used in the real world. In particular they would like to optimize `printf("...\n")` into `puts` calls with no format string/va_arg parsing and other such CPU expensive bloat. And that optimization is only possible if `puts` return value works the same as `printf`. And therefore that's how all compilers and standard libs do it.

Comment: @Lundin on my platform `puts("Foo")` returns 0. It may be unusual, but it's conforming.

Comment: @Jabberwocky what platform and compiler are you using? I honestly never checked the return value of `puts` except against `EOF` so I'm curious about why it might be different

Comment: @JohnDoe nor did I. I'm using MSVC (yes I know, it's not the most conforming C platform).

Comment: @Jabberwocky  The thing is: the people who wrote the functions for stdio.h in the 1970s where completely clueless about how to design useful and rugged APIs. They likely didn't write a spec at all but just aimlessly hacked away. Some 20 years later that old crap became part of the standard and some poor soul had to formalize it. It is by far the worst library every written for _any_ programming language, the flaws are numerous and severe. It should have been replaced by a better library back in the 1980s.

Comment: @Lundin 100% agree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard ([C99](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) paragraph 7.19.7.10), which also describes some aspects of the C standard library, says that:

> The `puts` function returns `EOF` if a write error occurs; otherwise it returns a nonnegative value.

Therefore, it is up to the specific library implementation to choose exactly which value to return. As long as the value is not negative, it means the call was successful. A conforming C library implementation can return `0`, `12345`, the number of characters printed, or a just any random non-negative integer. Therefore, the programmer should not make assumptions about the specific return value.

The correct way to test for success would then be:

```c
if (puts(...) != EOF) {...}
// or
if (puts(...) >= 0) {...}
```

If the above tests pass (you enter the `if` body), then the string was correctly printed.

Comment: So there is no "specific" return value, I mean I can't know the return value beforehand?

Comment: @Shashaank yes, exactly. You should not make assumptions on the return value.

Comment: Oh Ok @MarcoBonelli Thank you :-)